# Form data doesnt't get sent by id via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want the following ajax request to process form data from form with "#next" id:

```
$(function () {
    $("#next").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'check_user.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if(response['found'] === 'true') {
                    location.href = 'index.php';
                } else {
                    alert('Incorrect username or password');
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here's the file that contains the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/auth_style.css">
    <title>Authentication</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/authentication_ajax.js"></script>
    <noscript>JS is disabled. Enable js to continue</noscript>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="header">Enter your data here</h1>

<form id="#next">
    <label for="login">Login</label>
    <input type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Enter your login here" required><br>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password here" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>

<form id="#log_out" action="log_out.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Log out</button>
</form>
</body>
```

What's interesting is that when I used just `$('form').on('submit', function (e) {` it worked just fine.

Comment: `$('#next').serialize()` instead of `$('form').serialize()`, because you have multiple forms. (the event work because is assign to each form and when you click the button will submit correctly)

Answer (score 1):

You have two error the first one is how to use ids, in the id don't use `#` instead use just the name, and into the selector you can use `$('#name')`.
The second problem is about selector of `serialize()`, in this case you can use directly `e.target` like:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#next").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(e.target).serialize());
    /*
    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'check_user.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(e.target).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if(response['found'] === 'true') {
                    location.href = 'index.php';
                } else {
                    alert('Incorrect username or password');
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
        */
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="header">Enter your data here</h1>
<form id="next">
  <label for="login">Login</label>
  <input type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Enter your login here" required><br>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password here" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>

<form id="log_out" action="log_out.php" method="post">
  <button type="submit">Log out</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Or you can also write `$(this).serialize()` too.